# how to play you tube embeded code in android application?

Tags: android, video, embedded, youtube

Hi all this is my youtube embed code.
But I have no idea about this how to play this in android application?
Can we play this in webview or device player ?

```
"object width="441" height="353"  
param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?fs=1" param  
param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" param  
param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" param  
embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?fs=1"  
type="application/x-shockwave-flash"  
allowfullscreen="true"  
allowscriptaccess="always"  
width="441" height="353"  
embed>  
object"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this to launch the default device player -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
// use this if you want to launch from a non activity class
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanx . but how to integrate this embaded code in your code ? plz help me if u have any idea

Comment: You can put your link into a String called url and then use Uri.parse(url)

Comment: i have tried this but its not working ... as url i have put the above embed code as string .

Comment: embadedurl= "<object width="441" height="353">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?fs=1"</param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?fs=1"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
allowfullscreen="true"
allowscriptaccess="always"
width="441" height="353">
</embed>
</object>
";Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(embadedurl));
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        this.startActivity(intent);

Comment: What do you mean that it does not work , Does your code throw any exception ? If you are writing this code in a class that extends from Activity then you don't need  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: "no activity found to handle INTENT"

Comment: atandroid.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult

Comment: I guess the android emulator does not come with a default player,you need to try this on an android device.

Comment: Its working on Android 1.6 device ?  My code launches the default player so it may not work on an emulator.

Comment: its now working in 1.6 Emulator and also in my galaxy tab device yet.any other idea to play this embaded code in webview or any thing?

Comment: I have not tested this code on 1.6,but it works on 2.2 device.

Comment: its not working in my Tab . how to send my full code to you ?